# How to add/find student details and print them

Tags: c#

I want to add code to StudentData in AddStudent and FindStudent.

In Program.cs How can do that which are in commented lines.

Here's my database class:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class Database
    {
        public static void initializeDatabase()
        {
            var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
            dbConnection.Open();

            try
            {
                SQLiteCommand command =
                    new SQLiteCommand(
                        "create table Student (NAME varchar(255), PHONENUMBER varchar(255), ADDRESS varchar(255))",
                        dbConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                command =
                    new SQLiteCommand(
                        "INSERT INTO Student (NAME, PHONENUMBER, ADDRESS) VALUES('Andy Rob','(000) 000-0000', '1500 Logan Drive, Walter, TN')",
                        dbConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        public static SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
            dbConnection.Open();

            return dbConnection;
        }

        public static void CleanUp()
        {
            var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
            dbConnection.Open();

            try
            {
                SQLiteCommand command =
                    new SQLiteCommand(
                        "drop table Student",
                        dbConnection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's Student Class

```
namespace SampleApp
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string name;
        public string phoneNumber;
        public string address;
    }
}
```

Here's IStudent Interface

```
   public interface IStudent
    {
        Student findStudent(string firstName, string lastName);
        void addStudent(Student newStudent);
    }
```

Here's StudentData Class

```
namespace SampleApp
{
    public class StudentData : IStudent
    {
        public void AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Student findStudent(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's Program .cs

```
class Program
    {
        private StudentData studentData = new StudentData();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                DatabaseUtil.initializeDatabase();
                /* TODO: create student objects and put them in the StudentData and database
                * Ravi, (922) 222-2222, 1411 Tyson Dr, Oak Farms, TN



                // TODO: print the Student Data out to System.out
                // TODO: find Ravi and print out just her entry
                // TODO: insert the new student objects into the database

            }
            finally
            {
                Database.CleanUp();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you know how to write (or were given) `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO SQL` statements - now do some research on `SELECT`. Or if that's not the issue add exactly what you're stuck on.  "What do I do now?" is too vague a question for this forum.

Comment: updated this above

Comment: Even after the update the question is too vague and the answer is most likely "learn how to use `SELECT`"

Comment: Now i have updated

Comment: Okay so you have four TODOs you are stuck on and have not shown any attempts or evidence of research.  SO is not a training site - there are lots of examples on this site and many others that can help you learn what you need to do.  Come back with _specific_ questions after you have shown attempts (even failed ones) on your own.

Comment: I'm confused as to your actual question here.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a SELECT query to get the student with the matching name.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Students
WHERE Name = {0}
```

Please note that you have to String.Format that with the name you are looking for.

However I would suggest you to look into [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/), which takes care of working with the database, meaning you only have to deal with objects.

Comment: How to do Add Student and Find Student

Comment: You already know how to add a student (`INSERT INTO`) and I described how to find one. If you have any more conceptual questions, I am happy to help, but you should be able to implement these methods yourself now.